# Wrapping the arguments or result of an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

I want to reassign an anonymous function to add to what it does. I'm basically looking the below functionality.

```js
let f1 = (x: number) => x + 100;
// f1 = (x: number) => f1(x) + 20; // becomes recursive -> stack overflow, not what I want
f1(3) // 123
```

The two options I see are either 1. wrapping the argument or 2. somehow wrapping the result. The first option seems easier but I'm not sure how to accomplish it (or if what I'm asking for is impossible).

Edit: Evidently my question was not clear enough. I've made a new example.

https://tsplay.dev/mpv3Mw

```js
class Cat {
    eat() {
        const newCat = createFullCat(this);
        return newCat;
    }
    drink() {
        const newCat = createQuenchedCat(this);
        return newCat;
    }
    sleep() {
        const newCat = createRestedCat(this);
        return newCat;
    }
}

function makeCatActionChain(makeCatSleep: boolean, makeCatEat: boolean) {
    let f1 = (cat: Cat) => cat.drink();

    if (makeCatEat) {
        f1 = (cat: Cat) => f1(cat).eat(); // Need different way to do this
    }

    if (makeCatSleep) {
        f1 = (cat: Cat) => f1(cat).sleep(); // Need different way to do this
    }
    return f1;
}
```

If possible I would like to do this without creating another variable.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are trying to accomplish. The commented out code is a recursive function without an exit condition so it is not surprising that it is going to overflow. Can you explain why `f1(3)` should return 123?

Comment: Can't you just assign the original `f1` value to another variable so that you can still access it after the variable is reassigned, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAvM1W)?  You can start wrapping things like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbG42W) but it seems unnecessary unless you have a specific use case in mind for it.

Comment: All recursive functions need a base case that terminates the recursion, and some way of updating - of converging _toward_ that base case.

Comment: @jcalz Apologies for the confusion. I've updated my question with a clearer example. I understand that I can simply use two variables, what I would like to know is a way to do it without creating two variables. Your suggested wrapping method would work, it would be nice if there was a less unwieldy way to do this.

Comment: @JH- What exactly is `makeCatActionChain` suppose to do and could you provide an example of how you want to use it? It sounds like you want to chain some function calls, and it feels the `makeCatActionChain` is suppose to do some kind of status transition but the role of this function isn't really clear to me yet.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, the most appropriate description is that I want to create a function A that takes a set of arguments and returns a function B that takes a class instance and applies methods to it depending on the arguments given to function A. 
In other words, I want to create a function that creates a method chain based on the given arguments. When calling the method chain on an instance, the methods are applied to the instance.

Comment: Could you make that code a [mre] without undeclared things in it?  Your `createXXXCat()` functions don't exist so it's hard to test any solution.  Also, do you have a reason why you want your intermediate chain states to be stored in the same variable?  Mutating functions is... weird.  What's wrong with `const f1 = ...` and then `const f2 = condition ? f1 : (cat: Cat) => f1(cat).eat()` etc?

Comment: @jcalz Here's a [working example](https://tsplay.dev/mLLMem) that does exactly what I want. The problem is that in my real-life case 1. the Cat class is defined in a library and I can't access its prototype 2. It feels hacky and it would be nice if a better way was available.

Comment: @JH- I updated the answer. Is that somewhere near where you are trying to do?

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming?

Comment: What about [this way](https://tsplay.dev/NnXAqW)? Since the API seems to be returning a modified `Cat` at every step, I'd expect people to modify a `Cat` directly and not try to chain all the methods first and then apply them.  Does this meet your needs?  If not, please [edit] the code example to show the unsatisfied use cases.

Answer (score 2):

First, you assigned a value (a function) to `f1`:

```js
let f1 = (x: number) => x + 100;
```

Then, you assigned a new value (another function) to `f1`:

```js
f1 = (x: number) => f1(x) + 20;
```

When you assigned the new function to it, the previous function no longer had any references. In the new function, the reference to `f1` refers to itself, (so it will recurse forever when invoked).

If you want to maintain a reference to the first one so that it can be used in the second one, just give the second one a different name, like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgRhgXhgCgB4C4ZgK4C2ARgKYBOAlCgHwwYwDUMCADCwNwCwAUKJLHABMKdNlyFSlGvASYqTQRx58IIADYkAdGpABzNELQBmChXYwA9BeaCjQA)

```ts
const f1 = (x: number) => x + 100;
const f2 = (x: number) => f1(x) + 20;
console.log(f2(3)); // 123
```

---

If you want to apply a series of transformations on a number (but don't want to have to create a variable name for each transform function in your program), you could use an array of functions to process the number in order, like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4BVUEMB2BnAMwHtUEoBeKAChwC4odEVUBKCgPgabQG4BYAFCCCcHAGNgASyI4owbPmKl4yNNTpdVqADRyFhEgjz0VzTLgOkA2gF0W9RlqgBvQVCgAbCMChi4qVAgcH0ocfgF3JWoxGTwfAlkiAj0LJSM2PwCgkKgEqkzA4JZw90Dgf1kC7PCAX0FBGPwfeVTDY1huDH002wooW3CWxTaAOjA4PAALGg4GKABqKABGAAYV4sEhyyMxienZck5ZRYAmdfCG2J9AvDgPHK200zQqAGZdR7aNgUa8Ii8Rh4iABzKg3O7AYpQAD00OWJ1egiAA)

```ts
type NumberTransform = (n: number) => number;

function transformNumber (n: number, transforms: NumberTransform[]): number {
  let current = n;
  for (const fn of transforms) current = fn(current);
  return current;
}

const transforms: NumberTransform[] = [];
transforms.push(n => n + 100);
transforms.push(n => n + 20);

const result = transformNumber(3, transforms);
console.log(result); // 123
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is just two variables for your functions instead of reassign the `f1`.

```
const f1 = (x: number) => x + 100;
const f2 = (x: number) => f1(x) + 20;
f2(3) // 123
```

Based on the updated code sample, is this something that accomplish what you are talking about?

```js
function makeCatActionChain(makeCatSleep: boolean, makeCatEat: boolean) {
    if(makeCatSleep) {
        return (cat: Cat) => cat.drink().sleep();
    }

    if(makeCatEat) {
        return (cat: Cat) => cat.drink().eat();
    }

    //Assuming you always want the cat to drink
    return (cat: Cat) => cat.drink();
}
```

Comment: Apologies for my unclear question, I basically meant to ask "How do I do this without using two variables"

Comment: Oh I see. Then I don't think it is possible. What problem are you trying to solve? Why are you limited to the one variable?

Comment: I've added a new example to make clearer what kind of thing I'm trying to achieve.